# Definition of minimal "onsite backup"

Tags: backup, disaster-recovery

I've learned about a hosting provider who's definition of "onsite backup" includes "snapshots of the SAN storage stored on the same SAN and the same RAID 50 array".

Does this sound right to anyone? I mean - I expect everyone to say "it depends on what you are trying to protect from" but assuming it's meant to protect from a disaster above "accidental deletion". There is no other form of backups offered (e.g. they don't offer to copy the snapshot to another SAN array or to tapes, for instance).

Has anyone else found such a definition actually used in production environments?

Comment: at least they told you this upfront!

Comment: Without knowing just what is stored on that SAN we cannot know if such a snapshot is adequate for disaster recovery.

Comment: Have you considered whether switching providers based upon this particular little revelation is a concern for you? If not, just make sure you do your own backups and carry on.

Comment: You're likely protected against accidental deletion on your part. You're not likely protected against accidental deletion on their part, i.e., if the SAN somehow gets nuked, whether through some software/engineering error, or the cleaning crew tipping physically tipping over the SAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Backups are not on the same media as what's being backed up, by definition.

Comment: By whose definition? Like the OP said, one needs to define what they're trying to protect from before deciding what backup technology to use.

Comment: Backup gets you back up when you lose your data. It doesn't reduce the risk that you'll lose your data like raid or clones.

Comment: Thanks. Finally someone who actually read my question and tries to answer it.
As I said in my original question - I'd expect the backup to be useful against anything that's not just "accidental deletion". I think this includes media failure (disk or anything physically around it getting damaged making the disk inaccessible).
Is there some "industry-standard" definition of "onsite backup"?

Comment: Industry standard for a private datacenter, maybe. Not so much for hosting- they like to play a little fast and loose with definitions so they can sell more VPSes. What you need is backup software, possibly with an agent running on your machine, and then a schedule for full and incremental/differential backups.